How do I treat regression when I know that relationships/coefficients will differ between individuals in my dataset?
I have a large dataset made up of 100 climate simulations. Each simulation runs over 100 years and for each year I calculate a handful of metrics (features). I'm interested in measuring how well these features predict/correlate with how much heat has been added to the system (this relationship is very likely nonlinear).
However, each simulation has a different configuration, which affects both the magnitude of the features and labels, as well as the strength of the relationship between them. However, for any one simulation, I can assume that the relationship is (more or less) consistent.
How can I best assess whether these features are good predictors?
Some of the strategies I've thought about include:

Running separate regressions for each simulation, and then somehow analyse the distribution of coefficients (* somehow, this feels desperate*).
Run the analysis on the instantaneous rates of change rather than the magnitudes of my features/labels.

Finally, to frame it as a (maybe?) simpler example:
I have 10 jars of sand. They are different sizes, the sand is at different temperatures, and in each one there is some unknown volume of ice. I put the jars on the stove, and periodically measure the temperature at the top of the jar.

The bigger jars will warm up more slowly, as will the icy ones.
The magnitudes of the measurements will differ depending on the size of the jar and its initial temperature.
How do I best assess the sensitivity of my measurement to the change in heat content of the jar?


This suggestion may not be helpful / applicable but, for the jars of sand at least, is it possible to write down a formula for temperature as a function of the measured (volume of jar, ...) and the unknown (proportion of ice in jar, ...) quantities. Then estimate the parameters of that equation (+ the measurement error of course).
